# Proof of the Uniqueness of an Interpolated Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, roots

**Theorem** Let $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...,(x_n,y_n)$ be a collection of points in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}.$ Then the polynomial $P(x)$ satisfying $P(x_1)=y_1, P(x_2)= y_2,...,P(x_n)=y_n$ is unique.

*Proof*

Suppose we have $n$ points in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ with a polynomial $P_1(x)$ that passes through all $n$ points.  Toward a contradiction, suppose there also exists polynomial $P_2(x)$ satisfying the same property.

Consider $G(x)=P_1(x)-P_2(x)$. Then $G(x)$ has the following properties:

$\circ$ $G(x)$ is a polynomial.

$\circ$ $G(x)$ has degree $\leq n$ since $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$ are degree $n$ or less.

$\circ$ At any of the $n$ data points, $G(x_i)=P_1(x_i) - P_2(x_i) = y_i - y_i = 0.$ Therefore, $G(x)$ has $n+1$ roots.

But now we have a polynomial of degree $ \leq n$ with $n+1$ roots. This is a contradiction.

Therefore, our assumption was false and $P_1(x)=P_2(x)$ is unique. $\hspace{1cm} \square$

Comment: This is definitely the way to go! I wouldn't phrase it as a proof by contradiction, though: for any such $P_1$ and $P_2$, you've shown that $P_1-P_2$ has degree at most $n$ and has $n+1$ roots. There is one such polynomial, however—the zero polynomial. That proves that $P_1-P_2=0$, which is what we want.